# Function tree issues

Tags: function, tree

I am creating a mutliple function process and I am having a small issue with he first function. Here is the code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class BradySkuzaLab8 
{

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
        int functionchoose = 0;
        int a = 0;
        int b = 0;
        int c = 0;
        int Maxval = 0;

        do
        {
        System.out.println( "Which function would you like to run?");
        System.out.println( "1) Max int funtion." );
        //System.out.println( "2) ");
        //System.out.println( "3) ");
        //System.out.println( "4) ");
        //System.out.println( "5) ");
        //System.out.println( "6) ");
        //System.out.println( "7) ");
        System.out.println( "8) Quit" );
        functionchoose = kb.nextInt();

            if(functionchoose == 1)
            {
                System.out.println("Please input a: ");
                a = kb.nextInt();
                System.out.println( "Now b: ");
                b = kb.nextInt();
                System.out.println( "And c: ");
                c = kb.nextInt();
                System.out.println(Maxval);

            }
        }
        while(functionchoose != 8);
        {
        }

    }

public static int Maxval(int a, int b, int c)
{
    int Maxval;
    Maxval = Math.max(a, Math.max( b, c));

   return Maxval;
}
}
```

After I enter a, b, c, I set the function to choose the max value but it always prints out 0 for me. I was wondering what I was doing wrong in this instance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a confusing situation where you have named a variable and a method the same thing.  What you need to do is change your println line to

```
System.out.println(Maxval(a,b,c));
```

But in reality, it is a bad idea to have a variable and a method with the same name. I'm not sure exactly what you're planning on doing with the variable Maxval, but for now, you don't need it and can just get rid of it by deleting the line that says

```
int Maxval = 0;
```

Comment: thank you for the help man. this answered my question. as for what i was doing i guess i overthought it and it doesnt make that much sense now that i think of it.